# Blue patch appear after subtracting image background in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I have tried image subtraction in MatLab, but realised that there is a big blue patch on the image. Please see image for more details.

[image]
Another images showing where the blue patch approximately cover till.
[image]

The picture on the left in the top 2 images shows the picture after subtraction.You can ignore the picture on the right of the top 2 images. This is one of the original image:
[image]

and this is the background I am subtracting.
[image]

The purpose is to get the foreground image and blob it, followed by counting the number of blobs to see how many books are stacked vertically from their sides. I am experimenting how blobs method works on matlab.

Do anybody have any idea? Below is the code on how I carry out my background subtraction as well as display it. Thanks.

```
[filename, user_canceled] = imgetfile;
fullFileName=filename;
rgbImage = imread(fullFileName);


folder = fullfile('C:\Users\Aaron\Desktop\OPENCV\Book Detection\Sample books');
baseFileName = 'background.jpg'; 
fullFileName = fullfile(folder, baseFileName);

backgroundImage =imread(fullFileName);
rgbImage= rgbImage - backgroundImage;

%display foreground image after background substraction%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

subplot( 1,2,1);
imshow(rgbImage, []);
```

Comment: The pictures help, but the code does not help right now.  Could you explain a little more about where the data is coming from?  Is `rgbImage` read in from a file, and so is `backgroundImage`?  Where does this data come from?  Have you done any sort of sanity check to ensure that the problem is in the code and not in the data itself?

Comment: Also, it is quite likely that straight subtraction is not the right answer.  For example, say the rgb values are each between 0 and 255.  What is the desired outcome if the blue value of a given pixel is 25 and the corresponding blue value in the background image is 200? Should the new pixel value be -175?  Obviously not.  That is most likely what you are seeing here.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advice in regarding the code. I have edited the question to include more of the codes. Please take a look. I am unsure if the problem is in the code or in the data. I have only been using MatLab for about 5 days, hence is not really similar to the syntax yet. In regard to why I use straight subtraction, I found the method from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008326/background-subtracting-in-matlab/3008840#3008840, one of the answers given in that question.

Comment: the answer wrote: "If you want to subtract a constant value, or a background with the same size as your image, you simply write img = img - background. imsubtract". Or do you think I should substract the background via another method?

Comment: It might be worth re-reading the answer Jonas gives to that post.  He says that *background subtraction* is easy, but he goes on to imply that it may not actually be what the OP is after.

Comment: Where do these images actually come from?  What are you trying to get rid of by subtracting the background?  What information are you trying to obtain after you "subtract" the background? Is the image on the left the background, and the image on the right is after subtraction?  Rather than answering in the comments, consider revising your question so that it explains what the data is that you have to work with, what information you are trying to recover from that data, and what we are seeing in the pictures.

Comment: Hey, as suggested, I have edited my question to explain the purpose. Cheers. and what are the images you are looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the foreground objects (i.e. the books) are opaque, the background does not affect those pixels at all.  In other words, you are subtracting out something that is not there.  What you need is a method of detecting which pixels in your image correspond to foreground, and which correspond to background.  Unfortunately, solving this problem might be at least as difficult as the problem you set out to solve in the first place.

If you just want a pixel-by-pixel comparison with the background you could try something like this:

```
thresh = 250;
imdiff = sum(((rgbImage-backgroundImage).^2),3);
mask = uint8(imdiff > thresh);
maskedImage = rgbImage.*cat(3,mask,mask,mask);
imshow(maskedImage, []);
```

You will have to play around with the threshold value until you get the desired masking.  The problem you are going to have is that the background is poorly suited for the task.  If you had the books in front of a green screen for example, you could probably do a much better job.

[image: Result image showing books with background removed]

Comment: Thanks and agreed, but if let's say there is only one thin book, meaning the foreground takes up only less than 10 to 20% of the picture and there is 80 percent of the background, thresholding the image before I blob it may not go as smooth as I would like it to most of the time. Hence, the reason for subtracting the background. Basically, when I was using Visual Studio C, I am doing a comparison of the two images(one background and one with books) and removing all the pixels are similar. I was wondering if there is a similar method to remove the background in MatLab?

Comment: See my edit for a simple version of the technique you are describing.

Comment: I get the following errors, when I tried your method. Error using repmat
Too many input arguments. and error in line, mask = repmat(uint8(imdiff > thresh),1,1,3); I think it got to do with the parameters of repmat? I googled about it, but how do we know what is the best last 2 parameter value to give?

Comment: It works fine for me.  However, now that you mention it, I have seen inconsistent implementations of `repmat` in the past when it comes to dimensions greater than 2.  I have edited the code to use `cat` instead of `repmat`.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. MatLab's convention of image processing is really different from Visual Studio C++ with OpenCV, that I find it difficult to grasp the conventions and methods via self study and experiments. I foresee alot more problems in the near future. but Thanks alot(: I learnt something today.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting blue patches because you are subtracting two color RGB images. Ideally, in the difference image you expect to get zeros for the background pixels, and non-zeros for the foreground pixels. Since you are in RGB, the foreground pixels may end up having some weird color, which does not really matter.  All you care about is that the absolute value of the difference is greater than 0.

By the way, your images are probably uint8, which is unsigned. You may want to convert them to double using `im2double` before you do the subtraction.

Comment: Thanks, I did convert them to im2double, and converting back to uint8, etc. but the result still have no difference, the blue patch is still there. Any other idea?

Comment: Wait, you don't need to convert back to uint8. You should use im2double on both the object and the background images, and then use abs(rgbImage - backgroundImage).

Comment: Yup. tried that, it give a slightly different results, but still failing to extract the foreground image as I hoped to. Its weird, considering that when i used visual studio c++ and opencv, and used the exact same method of comparison, it is successful. I still trying to understand the syntax and how MatLab really works. I managed to solved it though, using a mask as nispio mentioned. Thanks for your help. I greatly appreciate it (: