# Image segmentation in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I am trying to extract just the currency image from the an image of a currency taken on white paper. I tried median filter to get the background and use a simple subtraction like:
    image=image-background.
But I got two problems: 1) The median filter is too slow. 2) The resulting image is not as my expectation.
Here is the image:

[image]

Any better way to do it, please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Background subtracting in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008326/background-subtracting-in-matlab)

Comment: detect edges using `edge`, run hough transform to find long boundaries of note. use ransac to vote for rectangle.

Comment: @Shai I did what you have advised me. Use sobel to detect edge and apply [H,T,R] = hough(Edge); But how do I apply "ransac to vote rectangle"?

Answer (score 1):

You can try detecting the boundary of the note using edge detection and the hough transform.  Alternatively, you can find the boundary using the `activecontour` function.

Another possibility is to detect the note using hue, using the fact that it is green and the background is not.  Transform the image to HSV color space using `rgb2hsv`, and then use `greythresh` on the hue component.

By the way, this is more of an image segmentation problem. *Background subtraction* usually refers to separating moving objects from a static background in video.

Comment: I used edge detection and the hough transform ([H,T,R] = hough(Edge)), but how can I actually extract the note from the image finally? I couldn't try acivecontour because it is not supported in R2012a version. I tried your other possibility, to use HSV and apply greythresh on the hue component,it gave me a black image(which is the note) on a white background. But how can I extract the note from it? I hope I can get back the rgb format of the extracted note, because that is what I am looking for at the end for color comparison of different notes, not only just this green note.

Comment: If you have an image where the note is black and everything else is white, you are almost there.  Let `im` be your original image.  Let `mask` be your black and white image.  Then you can get the pixels that belong to the note by using logical indexing: `im(mask == 0)`.